# STM32, power up working once

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I'm currently working on a small project, an STM32F070F6 uC connected to an oled display via i2C. I also added a LED for debugging purposes. The whole thing is powered by a 3V cr2032 battery and a switch can open/close the power rail. Everything is working fine while the st-link debugger is connected (oled and led toggles). Once powered down and st-link removed, I switch the power back on, the device is working fine but switching off and on again the device won't boot anymore. BOOT pin is well set to 0 via a 10K resistor, reset is high. Im trying to figure out what could cause this and how st-link is related to this issue since it doesnt provide any power. I was thinking about decoupling caps...

[image]

Edit : adding 10µF electrolytic decoupling cap in parallel with the batterry doesn't change the behavior. Further information : when reset button is pushed the device doesn't boot after reset button released.

Edit :
I monitored power supply voltage at power up, with or without debbuger the following figure is what I have :
[image]

Comment: Especially in combination with your discrete LED, your OLED is likely too much for the coin cell at least in operation, even if it isn't your startup issue.  While you wouldn't think so, protection diodes mean that the SWD lines actually may supply power to keep the chip alive.  The test you should do right now is to substitute a good 3v3 power supply for the coin cell.

Comment: It's also unclear if you have suitable pull-ups for the I2C, or if you have any means of determining if the code is running *other* than the I2C leading to success drawing on the OLED.  You might try adding some serial output or blipping a GPIO you can watch with a scope or something...

Comment: Pull-ups are present in the OLED display module. I tried your advice, I removed the LED and I connected a voltmeter instead and also disconnected the OLED display and replaced the coin cell by a lab power supply. It doesn't boot without the st-link and even stranger thing, it doesnt boot without the OLED display connected ! I monitored the voltmeter to see if the code is running or not. I didn't mention I have a button matrix connected to the others IOs I will try to unsolder those to highlight any conflict...

Comment: Repeating the previous question, what is your criteria for determining that the MCU has booted???  If you have code that tries to talk to an I2C peripheral, and that peripheral is not there, it may well get stuck.  How are your monitoring the software state otherwise???

Comment: My criteria was the monitoring of my led output (led is removed, I connected a voltmeter). In the code the output toggles every sec. I followed your advice and I removed the code concerning the i2c (im using the provided lib by ST I would think they are non blocking but anyway). In that configuration I can do power cycles without problem at boot, only issue occurs when harware reset is activated the device won't boot after it)

Comment: Try removing or shrinking the reset capacitor or adding an external pullup say 4.7K

Comment: Measure the voltage at power up without debugger, I suspect voltage drops at power up. The debugger could actually power the device in some degree, since (if I remember correctly) the debug pins are pulled high by debugger. Also check the battery switch for "bouncing problems".

Comment: I monitored the power supply from cr2032 at power up and added it to my original post. Do you think this part (stm µC) is suited for this application ? I will try the same test with a low-power part like stm32L0 next week, hoping it will solve my problem. (This custom board is working fine when powered by an ld1117s33tr, no strange behavior with reset and debbuger)

Comment: The STM32 is suitable;  **what is not suitable especially with the OLED is the coin cell!**.  Until you address the power supply problem pointed out weeks ago by replacing the coin cell with something capable of providing the needed current, there's really no other help that can be offered.

Comment: There is no OLED display connected in my last tests. One of them was to power the board with a lab power supply which can provide 3A and the results were the same unfortunatly. Something is not right.